# how to merge 3gp audio files?

Tags: files

Any software available for joining/merging multiple 3gp audio files in lubuntu? All available online softwares are for Windows/Mac only.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is pretty powerful,  check the answer by @rogerdpack over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg), alternatively (I am not familiar with 3gp, so it is just a try) you might just concatenate them via `cat` : `cat file1.3gp file2.3gp > new_file.3gp`

Comment: Not sure if it works, but have you tried `cat 1.3gp 2.3gp > 3.3gp`?

Comment: @Fiximan; @Eduardo Cola: Tried your suggested method, but it's not working. The error message reads: No such file or directory.

Comment: You of course need to be in the folder where the files are and replace the "1.3gp" etc with the respective names of your files. For changing dirs use the `cd` command. If you are not familiar consult an introduction on how to use the command line. As the message reads: the files are not there so you did not put existing file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems like command line programs are not an option for you. So here comes my GUI recommendation: **Audacity**.

Audacity is a great free, open source, cross-platform audio editor. With it you can merge, cut, record, apply effects and do hundreds of editions in audio files. It also supports video files (the audio is extracted) and has great integration with most desktop environments (including drag/drop). It also encodes/exports your projects stunningly fast (even in higher qualities).

It's available for Linux/Unix, Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows.

Fortunately, Audacity is in Ubuntu's official repositories, so you can install it using the Software Center. Search for Audacity and install it.

You can also do it through command line, running

`sudo apt-get install audacity`

Here's their official website, where you can get more information:

http://www.audacityteam.org

Comment: Maybe worthwhile mentioning, that if you run into problems with Audacity, you may have to add the PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu to your software sources. It gets the 2.1.2 version. I had problems with an earlier release of Audacity.

Comment: @Eduardo Cola: Thanks a ton for your help pal. Appreciate it. With your advice and a little helping hand from an youtube tutorial, I was ablr to use Audacity to my benefit. Incidentally, you are right: command line is not my cup of tea. Thanks again.

Comment: @theodorn: Thank you all for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.3gp` files are all in the same folder and you have access to recent copy of FFmpeg you can try something like the following with:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(find . -name '*.3gp' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n") -c copy output.3gp
```

I tested this with multiple `.3gp` files on my system and it works flawlessly. If you do not have access to a recent copy of FFmpeg you can always have a look here:

[Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

where you will find simply copy and paste directions for building the most recent FFmpeg.

**Reference:**

- [Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: No worries, come to the commandline methods one day and you will be surprised how after a little while it all makes sense :)

Comment: @pestrnko: According to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate the option `-safe 0` is necessary only for absolute paths which don't occur in this case.